# Negative Rewards(punishment) processing in Human Brain?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, brain

Can someone please tell me how negative rewards or punishments are processed in the human brain? Do we have a separate segment to process positive and negative reward and are the positive and negative rewards processed in the same fashion?

Comment: What do you mean by 'segment'? We expect questions here to be based on a minimal amount of initial research. Could you include some references to things this question is based on?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by positive or negative rewards or punishments - these are very different terms?  Do you perhaps mean pleasure and pain instead?  I think this is a duplicate of: [Do we understand the non-subjective mechanisms behind pleasure and pain?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/488/7001) or possibly [Is there a region of the brain that mediates pain in a manner reminiscent of the mesolimbic pathway?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20736/7001)